# Google App Engine url path lost with www subdomain

Tags: google-app-engine, path, dns, subdomain, url-routing

I just moved a couple of static websites onto Google's App Engine, where, if you want to use your own domain, a www subdomain is required. Both domains are routing correctly, with the exception that one's full url path doesn't get passed on to the subdomain unless a www is typed or present in the link; without www, pages redirect home.

The working site—either link will work:
http://www.synth.tk/daw/
http://synth.tk/daw/

The problem site—only the first link will work; the second redirects to the homepage:
http://www.carolyncaton.com/photos/
http://carolyncaton.com/photos/

Both domains are set up with FreeDNS using the following host records as per Google's instructions:

```
 @  |   A   | 216.239.32.21
 @  |   A   | 216.239.34.21
 @  |   A   | 216.239.36.21
 @  |   A   | 216.239.38.21
www | CNAME | ghs.google.com
```

And both are using the following `app.yaml` file:

```
application: app-name-here
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

default_expiration: "30d"

handlers:

- url: /(.*\.css)
  mime_type: text/css
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.css)

- url: /(.*\.html)
  mime_type: text/html
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.html)
  expiration: "1h"

- url: /(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.js)

- url: /(.*\.eot)
  mime_type: application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.eot)

- url: /(.*\.(svg|svgz))
  mime_type: images/svg+xml
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(svg|svgz))

- url: /(.*\.ttf)
  mime_type: font/truetype
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.ttf)

- url: /(.*\.woff)
  mime_type: application/x-font-woff
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.woff)

- url: /(.*\.pdf)
  mime_type: application/pdf
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.pdf)

# image files
- url: /(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))

# index files
- url: /(.+)/
  static_files: static/\1/index.html
  upload: static/(.+)/index.html
  expiration: "15m"

- url: /(.+)
  static_files: static/\1/index.html
  upload: static/(.+)/index.html
  expiration: "15m"

# site root
- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html
  expiration: "15m"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using developer console in Chrome (F12, click the "preserve log upon navigation" button) you can see that http://carolyncaton.com/photos/ gets a 302 response to http://www.carolyncaton.com/. Since App Engine doesn't support naked (apex) domains, the problem must be elsewhere. I suggest you check FreeDNS for a setting like 'preserve path'.

Comment: The working case gives a 301 redirect to the proper file (/daw), the failing case gives a 302 redirect to the base url (/).  I'm not sure if there's any setting in your A assignment that can affect this.

Answer (score 0):

Google Appengine does not support 'naked domains', see
http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/kb/general.html#naked_domain

Comment: I'm thinking maybe you didn't fully read my post. Have another look. The question is, why does one forward to www correctly, while the other fails to pass the full url path.

Answer (score 0):

Both sites seem to work now.  Perhaps it just took a while for the nameserver updates to propagate.

Comment: They were both working all along, just that one redirects to the homepage unless a www is present, while the other takes you to the right place with or without a www.

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand the question.  The typical way to "bump" questions on SO is to issue a bounty, or get your question upvoted.  I don't know the answer to your question, but have you checked to see that the DNS entries are all exactly the same?  Are there any extra CNAME entries or other redirection in the working case?

Comment: Are you redirecting using the the Google Apps domain settings?  There's definitely something fishy going on there, you're getting a different redirect (302) with carolyncaton.com.  I'd play around with the Google Apps domain settings, maybe remove the mapping and add it back again.